# How to make procedural textures to follow geometry?

Tags: materials, texturing, uv

I know this may be a very basic question, but I somehow got myself tangled up.

I'm trying to make procedural textures (like clouds) to follow the geometry of a simple model, for instance, a distorted plane.

I'm satarting from a plane and then adding twists and bends to it.

by now it's not working for me:
The texture grain will not follow the direction of the breaks, but will stay in the original direction, as in this picture.
[image]

These are the settings of the texture:
[image]

Maybe the problem is in the Mapping settings for the Projection and the Coordinates. Or maybe there's something I should set up with the geometry first (my guess is something with the UV's ¿?¿ which i know nothing about).

I appreciate any help or hints. As you may help me clarify i can edit the question to be more detailed and specific.

And here's a video, where it simply happens,

http://youtu.be/sxgwa-0e5Jw?t=46s

...And the author itself responds in one of the comments (mine by the way) That this happens because the texture is like "the pattern on a carpet" so it will naturally follow if you bend or twist it...
So maybe it's even as simple as I'm not using the right tools to twist and bend the plane..... (wich were just extrude and subdivide....)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try UV unwrapping your plane and then using the UV coordinates in *Textures > Mapping*.

Comment: So first, i add the plane, then unwrap it, then apply the texture and finally i choose UV coordinates? (i'll give it a try now) thanks!

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3 ,It's working now, but i still don't get it completly, i think you've got to set the texture first .... but i'm still not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Using **UV** mapping, This is often the most straightforward method since you can edit UV's directly and preview the changes realtime, However you only get 2D coordinates, but you have the advantage that the coordinates are editable and are stored per face-corner (they dont have to be contiguous). UV's are also well supported by many formats, game-engines and render-engines.

  - if your mesh has primarily a grid topology, then try the **Follow-Active-Quads** tool from the unwrap menu.
- Using **Generated** mapping, this works when you deform a mesh by a modifier (ShapeKey, Lattice or Armature for example), the un-deformed mesh is used for texture coordinates.
- Using **TexMesh**, see Mesh Data properties, This allows you to select another mesh to use for texture coordinates, this gives a lot of control but the vertex indices must match up. These have the advantage of allowing you to set XYZ coordinates, but you have to take care not to add/remove vertices from the mesh. While useful, this is a Blender specific feature.